# Making a text editor with multiple pages using richtextboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

i am trying to give my text editor multiple pages mode the problem is  when the richtextbox reaches the last line it resizes and add a scroll bar which is not what i want, i made a code to transfer the last line of the richtextbox to the one that follows but it's moving the whole text instead and it's kind of sluggish, any help would be appreciated

```css
 public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            protected static bool GetVisibleScrollbars(Control ctl)
            {
                int wndStyle = Win32.GetWindowLong(ctl.Handle, Win32.GWL_STYLE);
                bool vsVisible = (wndStyle & Win32.WS_VSCROLL) != 0;

                return vsVisible;
            }
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            List<RichTextBox> pages=new List<RichTextBox>();
            int currentdocindex = 0;
            
            public void AddPage()
            {

                RichTextBox B = new RichTextBox();
                B.Size = richTextBox1.Size;
                panel1.Controls.Add(B);
                B.Location = new Point(pages[pages.Count - 1].Location.X, pages[pages.Count - 1].Location.Y + richTextBox1.Height + 20);
                pages.Add(B);
                B.SelectionIndent = 20;
                B.SelectionRightIndent = 20;
                B.Enter += new EventHandler(richTextBox_Enter);
               
    }
            private void richTextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                int i = 0;
                foreach (RichTextBox box in pages)
                {
                    if (box == (RichTextBox)sender)
                    {
                        currentdocindex=i;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                label1.Text = (currentdocindex + 1).ToString();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pages.Add(richTextBox1);
                richTextBox1.SelectionIndent = 20;
                richTextBox1.SelectionRightIndent = 20;
                
            }

            private void richTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (RichTextBox box in pages)
                {
                    if(box==(RichTextBox)sender)
                    {
                        currentdocindex=i;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
    }

            bool added = false;
            

            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              
                  int correntPageIndex = currentdocindex;
                if (GetVisibleScrollbars(pages[currentdocindex]))
                {
                    if (!added)
                    {
                        AddPage();
                        added = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
      
                added = false;
                    
                    }
                }
               
                if(GetVisibleScrollbars(pages[correntPageIndex]))
                {

                    string LastLineText = pages[correntPageIndex].Lines[pages[correntPageIndex].Lines.Count() - 1];
                    int LastLineStartIndex = pages[correntPageIndex].Text.LastIndexOf(LastLineText);
                    pages[correntPageIndex].SelectionStart = LastLineStartIndex;
                    pages[correntPageIndex].SelectionLength = pages[correntPageIndex].Text.Length - 1;
                    LastLineText = pages[correntPageIndex].SelectedRtf;
                    pages[correntPageIndex].Text = pages[correntPageIndex].Text.Remove(LastLineStartIndex);
                    pages[correntPageIndex + 1].SelectionStart = 0;
                    pages[correntPageIndex+1].SelectedRtf = LastLineText;
                }
                      }
        }
        public class Win32
        {
            // offset of window style value
            public const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

            // window style constants for scrollbars
            public const int WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000;
            public const int WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000;

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        }
```

Comment: _Way_ too much code for a SO question, IMO.

Comment: Sorry noob here

Comment: I think the problem is using the timer to move lines, but idk what else should I use maybe an other thread idk been stuck here for days...

Answer (score 0):

`RichTextBox` is a pain for this sort of thing, because to mutate a small portion of text you have to actually select the text first (which it appears you're attempting to do) and ensure the change only affects that text. It's a little nasty on the memory usage, but you might be better served by determining how many characters you want per page and subscribing to the `KeyDown Event` to determine when you move to a new page.   Try to adapt something like this and see if it works better.

```
public void MyKeyDownHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
       if(this.CurrentPageControl.RTB.Text.Length >= MY_LIMITING_CONSTANT_I_SET)
         {  
             MyPageUserControl mpuc = new MyPageUserControl();            
             mpuc.RTB.Text = this.CurrentPageControl.RTB.Text.Split(' ').Last();
             thePageCollectionIPresumeYouHave.Add(mpuc);
             this.CurrentPageControl = thePageCollectionIPresumeYouHave.Last();
             mpuc.RTB.Focus();
         }
}
```

Caveat: I did that entirely from memory and without a chance to read all of your code ( I had to skim) because I'm at work.

Another Caveat: I assumed you put your RichTextBoxes in a custom "page" control.  If you didn't, I hope my code shows you why you might want to.

Comment: I can't predict the limit of the text the user might use multiple fonts and sizes, plus skipping lines etc..

Comment: That shouldn't matter with the above code, thought you may want to also `Split()` on Environment.NewLine to handle the skipped lines.  Storing fonts, however, is a very different story; that's a whole different type of information. It can be done, but you might be better off with a third party control that supports book-like paging.